# Android:I need to take a picture and store it in sqlite database and populate it in a recycler view

Tags: android, bitmap, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-camera

I need to take images and store it in a database so I can populate it in a recycler view I was able to capture bit map images but bitmap images are blurry
can anybody help me

Comment: Show us what you've done, like the code how you take the picture ecc...

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the `Bitmap` into `Byte`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream array = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, array);
byte[] data = array.toByteArray();
```

and declare the image column as `BLOB`